# Javascript regex: remove space(s) if not surrounded by a letter

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to clean some html text with javascript, there are white spaces included before and after some words (text is poorly formatted).

Currently I have this regex:

```
$("#" + target + " *").replaceText(/([\S][\u05B0-\u05C4]*)/gi, '<span class="marked">$1<\/span>');
```

This will capture all the non white-space characters and wrap them in a span element, but will not capture spaces between words (I need the span).

How would you solve this?

Comment: Is it intentional to use `\S` (all non white space)? Could you give example of input and desired output?

Comment: where does `$.fn.replaceText` come from?

Comment: somewhat unclear.  Can you provide example of desired output?

Comment: yeah, please example of a text input and output.

Comment: The \S was my attempt to capture all non white-space characters, it works but I'm losing the spaces in between words.

Forgot to mention: replaceText is from 
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/

The input is a text nested within a table element (td), each nested element contains white-spaces (indentations), also the actual text is also poorly formatted (many spaces after some lines). When I use the function it wraps all those white-spaces inside spans (indent spaces, and the text's leading/trailing spaces). All I want is just the text and spaces in between words.

Comment: So, basically you want to replace multiple spaces with one space? Something like `string_with_text.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ');`

Comment: First answer in [regex'ing html](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1081234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match multiple repeated (spaces) and replace them with a single space:

```
'Quick   Brown      Fox'.replace(/[ ]+/g, ' '); //returns 'Quick Brown Fox'
```

This will match multiple repeated `\n\r\t`(whitespace symbols - spaces, tabs, new-lines and line-breaks) and replace them with a single space:

```
'Quick     Brown    Fox'.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');  //returns 'Quick Brown Fox'
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/KctX7/)

I don't understand your explanation of what you're trying to achieve with `span` wraparounds, but you can do whatever you want with the output from above.

Comment: Why do you have `/[ ]+/g` instead of `/ +/g`?

Comment: @some: If `\s` in the second example is too broad a match; OP would be able to add other character references to match into the first pattern (e.g. `/[ \t]+/g`) without breaking it (would have happened with `/ \t+/g`). It is implied that a *set* of characters is being replaced, just so happens that it consists of only one character. You're right though, specifically in the first example there is no need for enclosing a single character in set brackets.